# hadoop installation directory error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup hadoop from the blog :    http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

I can do :

```
hduser@laptop:~$ wget    http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz
hduser@laptop:~$ tar xvzf hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz
```

after that when  I try to :

```
hduser@laptop:~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/hadoop
```

and it gives an error like No Such file or directory.

What is the main problem here?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just download either the Hortonworks Sandbox or Cloudera Quickstart VM?

Comment: If you would like to continue, though, did you `mkdir /usr/local/hadoop`?

Answer (score 1):

Once the hadoop is untarred , check the actual path where it has done this operation and verify the path you are on is correct .

hduser@laptop:~$ tar xvzf hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz .

hduser@laptop:~$ ls -lrt

And see if it is here

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do

```
 sudo mv ~/hadoop-2.6.0 /usr/local/hadoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with,

```
hduser@laptop:~$ tar xvzf hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz .
hduser@laptop:~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop
hduser@laptop:~$ mv hadoop-2.6.0 /usr/local/hadoop
```

Here, I found a very simple tutorial to install [apache hadoop single node cluster setup](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2016/01/apache-hadoop-single-node-cluster-setup.html)